# Como leer arreglos dentro de objetos JSON con retrofit 2 en android? error: " java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to"

Tags: android, android-studio, json, retrofit

estoy intentando consumir una `api` de un `localhost`, una vez creada genere el siguiente `JSON`

```
{"Users":[
         {"id":1,
          "username":"pepe123",
          "fname":"pepe",
          "lname":"jose",
          "dispositivo":[
                      {"clave":"1234",
                       "codigo":"678"},                                     
                      {"clave":"3423",
                       "codigo":"444"}]}]}
```

El cual sera consumido por mi `App` de `android`, estoy usando `retrofit` y por medio de la pagina `http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/` obtengo las respectivas `clases` para trabajar los datos de `JSON`, estoy haciendo un login y quiero acceder a los datos `"clave"` y `"codigo"` que son mis validadores para permitirme entrar a la `App`, aquí mis clases y mi adaptador de `retrofit`

```
public interface API {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/";

@GET("Apidata")
Call<Responsejson>  getdata();

}
```

Las `clases` que se generan por medio de `http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/` :

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class dispositivo {

@SerializedName("clave")
@Expose
private String clave;
@SerializedName("codigo")
@Expose
private String codigo;

public String getClave() {
return clave;
}

public void setClave(String clave) {
this.clave = clave;
}

public String getCodigo() {
return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
this.codigo = codigo;
}

}

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Responsejson {

@SerializedName("Users")
@Expose
private List<User> users = null;

public List<User> getUsers() {
return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
this.users = users;
}

}

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class User {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;
@SerializedName("fname")
@Expose
private String fname;
@SerializedName("lname")
@Expose
private String lname;
@SerializedName("dispositivo")
@Expose
private List<dispositivo> Dispositivo = null;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
this.username = username;
}

public String getFname() {
return fname;
}

public void setFname(String fname) {
this.fname = fname;
}

public String getLname() {
return lname;
}

public void setLname(String lname) {
this.lname = lname;
}

public List<dispositivo> getDispositivo() {
return Dispositivo;
}

public void setDispositivo(List<dispositivo> Dispositvo) {
this.Dispositivo = Dispositivo;
}

}
```

Y aquí hago el llamado:

```
Call<Responsejson> users = API.getdata();
        users.enqueue(new Callback<Responsejson>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Responsejson> call, Response<Responsejson> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Responsejson responsejson = response.body();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Obtenido"+responsejson, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Responsejson> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Pero cuando ejecuto la aplicación no me lanza ningún dato, o ningún intento de dato siquiera, no se si estoy haciendo algo mal, o me falta algo, pero en el `log` lo único que me dice es.:

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/Apidata
    --> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:8000
```

Podrían darme alguna idea de por que pasa esto? gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no se debe al código, en realidad no estas accediendo a

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/Apidata
```

Primeramente debes recordar que necesitas definir dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` permiso para uso de internet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

El error especifico es que la url a la cual intentas acceder realizando una petición `GET` en realidad no esta disponible:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/Apidata
```

Esto puede deberse a algunas causas como son:

- No esta activado el [LocalHost](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRx7XiNruJc)
- Revisa si el puerto 8000 es el correcto.
- Tu firewall podría estar no permitiendo el acceso.

Comment: bueno los permisos están correctos, intentare con algunas de las soluciones que me has dado a ver si soluciono mi problema, estaré reportando cualquier cosa por acá.

Comment: reinicie el localhost y seleccione el puerto de nuevo y respondió, ahora trabajare en las consultas. gracias

Comment: Excelente @DavidVillegas , saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser un error el "localhost" ya que estas diciendo que se conecte localmente, caso contrario si estas conectado a una red local y tienes montada la base de datos en una pc o computadora coloca la dirección ip de lamaquina